# Is there a Android Google Maps v2 Marker Manager out there?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

I'm trying to find a way to manage the markers I have on a android map (v2) implementation in my app. I'd like to be able to draw markers that are inside the viewable boundary and at the same time only show markers above a certain zoom level. It seems like a common problem. So, I'm asking if anybody here uses something like a marker manager library or something. Just to make things easier and that I don't have to make one from scratch. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Not yet a manager, but you may want to check [Android Maps Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/), which has clustering functionality.

**Edit:**

In AME, drawing markers inside visible region can be achieved by using:

```
map.setClustering(new ClusteringSettings().addMarkersDynamically(true));
```

or

```
map.setClustering(new ClusteringSettings().enabled(false).addMarkersDynamically(true));
```

if you don't want clustering but only optimize for case when adding many markers.

Showing markers only when you hit a certain zoom level is not yet fully implemented, but already requested [here](https://github.com/mg6maciej/android-maps-extensions/pull/11).

Answer (score 1):

I realise that this question is pretty old but if anybody has still the same problem, one can use [Google Maps Android Marker Clustering Utility](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering#introduction).
Steps which should be taken are listed below:

1. Implement ClusterItem to represent a marker on the map. The cluster item returns the position of the marker as a LatLng object.
2. Add a new ClusterManager to group the cluster items (markers) based on zoom level.
3. Set the map's OnCameraChangeListener() to the ClusterManager, since ClusterManager implements the listener.
4. If you want to add specific functionality in response to a marker click event, set the map's OnMarkerClickListener() to the ClusterManager, since ClusterManager implements the listener.
5. Feed the markers into the ClusterManager.

Example implementation:

```
public class MyItem implements ClusterItem {
   private final LatLng mPosition;

   public MyItem(double lat, double lng) {
       mPosition = new LatLng(lat, lng);
   }

   @Override
   public LatLng getPosition() {
       return mPosition;
   }
}


private void setUpClusterer() {
    // Declare a variable for the cluster manager.
    private ClusterManager<MyItem> mClusterManager;

    // Position the map.
    getMap().moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(51.503186, -0.126446), 10));

    // Initialize the manager with the context and the map.
    // (Activity extends context, so we can pass 'this' in the constructor.)
    mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<MyItem>(this, getMap());

    // Point the map's listeners at the listeners implemented by the cluster
    // manager.
    getMap().setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
    getMap().setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);

    // Add cluster items (markers) to the cluster manager.
    addItems();
    }

private void addItems() {

    // Set some lat/lng coordinates to start with.
    double lat = 51.5145160;
    double lng = -0.1270060;

    // Add ten cluster items in close proximity, for purposes of this example.
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        double offset = i / 60d;
        lat = lat + offset;
        lng = lng + offset;
        MyItem offsetItem = new MyItem(lat, lng);
        mClusterManager.addItem(offsetItem);
    }
}
```

For more information you can check [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/#introduction) and the [library's Github page](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/)